# Text not displayed onclick of button in a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Here is what i am trying to do -

1. Send a GET request to the this API https://api.covid19india.org/data.json which returns JSON data
2. On my UI of chrome extension i have a button and a div
3. Display the JSON data received in div on click of the button

Code -

manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

   "name": "Custom Google Homepage",
    "description": "This extension shows a Google Image search result for the current page",
    "version": "1.0",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_title": "Click here!"
        },
    "permissions":[
        "tabs",
        "https://ajax.googleapis.com/",
        "https://api.covid19india.org/*"
    ],
    "content_scripts":[
        {
            "matches":[
                "<all_urls>"
            ],
            "js":["content.js"]
        }
    ]
}
```

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Hello</title>
    
    <style>
        #link
        {
            width: 70px;
            height: 25px;
        }
        #textt
        {
            width: 450px;
            height: 200px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="link">Extract !</button>
    <div id="textt" style="color: red; font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;"></div>
</body>
<script src="content.js"></script>
</html>
```

content.js

```
fetch('https://api.covid19india.org/data.json').then(r => r.text()).then(result => {
    // Result now contains the response text, do what you want...
    result = JSON.parse(result)
    console.log(result["statewise"])
    //alert(JSON.stringify(result["statewise"][0]))
    })

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        var div = document.getElementById('textt');
        var btn = document.getElementById('link');
        

        btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
            chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab){
                alert(JSON.stringify(result['statewise'][0]));
            });
            
            div.innerHTML += JSON.stringify(result['statewise'][0]);
        });
      });
```

I am able to console.log data received from JSON, but nothing is displayed when i click the button, where am i going wrong, please help !

Comment: document.addEventListener is it inside the fetch() or outside?

Comment: Outside the fetch , because i want to send the request to api as soon as the page loads and then whenever the user clicks the button the text should get displayed ! @Hadi Pawar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Remove the DOMContentLoaded line and its closing `});` - you don't need it because your script is at the end of the page so it already runs when DOM is loaded
2. Remove the entire `content_scripts` section from manifest.json
3. Rename content.js to popup.js because it's not a content script but a normal script used in the popup page
4. Move the code that uses `result` into the callback of `fetch` - the callback is asynchronous so the result should be used inside the callback
5. Use `json()` function in `fetch`
6. Check the correct devtools console - the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools - right-click inside the popup then click "inspect" to open its devtools

```
fetch('https://api.covid19india.org/data.json').then(r => r.json()).then(result => {
  const div = document.getElementById('textt');
  const btn = document.getElementById('link');
  btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    // ...............
  });
});
```